# How to sum this this JSON data values below

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate

I am Imran, Please see the JSON data below and tell how to sum the result below:

```
{
    "_id" : "59ae33130d83f7001112ea5e",
    "user" : {
        "passcode" : "****",
        "operator" : "premiereservices",
        "phone_num" : "8587366808",
        "balance" : 1.99
    },
    "location_id" : "58ec4e82addba5001160fc07",
    "customer_id" : "premiereservices",
    "shopping_cart" : {
        "item_count" : 2,
        "items" : [
            {
                "customer_id" : "premiereservices",
                "barcode" : "666",
                "description" : "Test Item",
                "price" : 1.99,
                "taxable" : false,
                "fixed_price_tax" : 0.05,
                "__v" : 0
            },
            {
                "customer_id" : "premiereservices",
                "barcode" : "777",
                "description" : "Test Item",
                "price" : 1.99,
                "taxable" : false,
                "fixed_price_tax" : 0.05,
                "__v" : 0
            }
        ],
        "total_due" : 4.08
    },
    "cart_total" : 4.08,
    "Date" : "2017-09-04T23:16:03-06:00",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "59ae38f186c7e70011a4e224",
    "location_id" : "58ec522a99da86001123ec47",
    "customer_id" : "premiereservices",
    "user" : {
        "phone_num" : "4129514766",
        "balance" : 0.03
    },
    "cart_total" : 3.55,
    "shopping_cart" : {
        "items" : [
            {
                "barcode" : "028400020008",
                "description" : "Smartfood White Cheddar Popcorn",
                "price" : 1.25,
                "taxable" : false,
                "tax_collected" : 0
            },
            {
                "barcode" : "012000286209",
                "description" : "Pureleaf Unsweetened Tea",
                "price" : 2.3,
                "taxable" : false,
                "tax_collected" : 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "Date" : "2017-09-04T23:41:05-06:00",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : "59ae3c569ce8ec00112775d6",
    "location_id" : "58ec522a99da86001123ec47",
    "customer_id" : "premiereservices",
    "user" : {
        "phone_num" : "7192358363",
        "balance" : 9.99
    },
    "cart_total" : 3.25,
    "shopping_cart" : {
        "items" : [
            {
                "barcode" : "10002",
                "description" : "GnG Burrito Bacon/GChili/Potato",
                "price" : 3.25,
                "taxable" : true,
                "tax_collected" : 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "Date" : "2017-09-04T23:55:34-06:00",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

## Result Will be

cart_total: 10.88

price: 10.78

tax_collected: 0

Please anybody help me what will be the aggregate query functions

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: { // for each document...
        cart_total: 1, // ...keep the "cart_total" field
        price: { $sum: "$shopping_cart.items.price" }, // ...sum up all "price" fields
        tax_collected: { $sum: "$shopping_cart.items.tax_collected" } // ...sum up all "price" fields
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null, // group all documents into the same bucket and sum up a bunch of values
        cart_total: { $sum: "$cart_total" },
        price: { $sum: "$price" },
        tax_collected: { $sum: "$tax_collected" }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0 // remove the "_id" field
    }
})
```